# Context eval expression when I write function in Mocha Test as lambda

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, cypress

When I use the below code, I do not get the context eval error for the variable data

```
 describe('Hooks',()=>{
    before(()=>{
        cy.fixture("example.json").then(function(data){
            this.data=data
        })
    })

    it("my First Test case", function(){
        cy.visit("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/")
        
        cy.get(":nth-child(1) > .form-control").type(this.data.name)
       
        cy.get("#exampleFormControlSelect1").select(this.data.gender)
    })
})
```

When write my mocha test function as lambda (Refer code below), I receive context eval error for data variable
**Code**

```
describe('Hooks',()=>{
    before(()=>{
        cy.fixture("example.json").then((data)=>{
            this.data=data
        })
    })

    it("my First Test case", () =>{
        cy.visit("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/")
        
        cy.get(":nth-child(1) > .form-control").type(this.data.name)
       
        cy.get("#exampleFormControlSelect1").select(this.data.gender)
    })
})
```

**Error**

> at Context.eval
> (webpack:///cypress/integration/examples/Test8Framework.js:4:13)
> From previous event:
> at Context.thenFn (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:155190:24)
> at Context.then (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:155629:22)
> at Context. (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:170229:22)
> at  (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169653:16)
> From previous event:
> at runCommand (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169632:9)
> at next (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169778:15)
> at  (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169806:17)
> From previous event:
> at next (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169778:35)
> From previous event:
> at Promise.catch.err.name (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169819:38)
> From previous event:
> at run (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169812:22)
> at $Cy.cy. [as fixture] (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:170269:12)
> at Context.runnable.fn (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:170496:22)
> at callFn (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104252:22)
> at Hook.../driver/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js.Runnable.run
> (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104239:8)
> at  (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:176219:29)
> From previous event:
> at Object.onRunnableRun (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:176207:18)
> at $Cypress.action (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:166637:29)
> at Hook.Runnable.run (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:174384:14)
> at next (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104754:11)
> at  (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104798:6)
> at timeslice (https://rahulshettyacademy.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:98724:28)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you store and access the fixture data using this test context
> object, make sure to use function () { ... } callbacks. Otherwise the
> test engine will NOT have this pointing at the test context.

This is mentioned in the [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#this-context). Hence in your test where you're using `it("my First Test case", () =>{` it is failing and when you're using `it("my First Test case", function(){` it is getting passed.